# EJB Container initialization error

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb

I'm trying to implement EJB order to communicate two jsf project.

I created an EAR in which there is my two jsf project + ejb .

Unfortunately I can not seem to launch the project.

```
WARNING: StatefulContainerbuilder instantiated store: org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.file.FileBackingStore@ece71a0; ha-enabled: false ==> BackingStoreConfiguration{clusterName='null', instanceName='null', storeName='Login-88570309275090944-BackingStore', shortUniqueName='88570309275090944', storeType='file', maxIdleTimeInSeconds=-1, relaxVersionCheck='null', maxLoadWaitTimeInSeconds=0, baseDirectoryName='C:\Users\Joff\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.2\config\GF3\domain1\session-store\Login-88570309275090944', keyClazz=interface java.io.Serializable, valueClazz=class org.glassfish.ha.store.util.SimpleMetadata, synchronousSave=false, typicalPayloadSizeInKiloBytes=0, vendorSpecificSettings={start.gms=false, async.replication=true, key.transformer=com.sun.ejb.base.sfsb.util.SimpleKeyGenerator@9bdd877, local.caching=true, value.class.is.thread.safe=true, broadcast.remove.expired=false}}
SEVERE: Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer load method
java.lang.RuntimeException: EJB Container initialization error
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.loadContainers(EjbApplication.java:242)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:108)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.load(ModuleInfo.java:186)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:264)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:460)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:212)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Erreur lors de la liaison du nom JNDI EJB.LoginRemote#EJB.LoginRemote pour l'EJB Login
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.initializeHome(BaseContainer.java:1553)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatefulSessionContainer.initializeHome(StatefulSessionContainer.java:213)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.ContainerFactoryImpl.createContainer(ContainerFactoryImpl.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.loadContainers(EjbApplication.java:230)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameAlreadyBoundException: Use rebind to override
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.doBindOrRebind(TransientContext.java:333)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.bind(TransientContext.java:268)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContextProviderImpl.bind(SerialContextProviderImpl.java:98)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.bind(LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.java:99)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.bind(SerialContext.java:672)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.bind(SerialContext.java:689)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.bind(InitialContext.java:423)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.bind(InitialContext.java:423)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.publishObject(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:208)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.publishObject(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:189)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer$JndiInfo.publish(BaseContainer.java:5629)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.initializeHome(BaseContainer.java:1540)
    ... 36 more

SEVERE: Exception while loading the app
SEVERE: Exception while loading the app : EJB Container initialization error
java.lang.RuntimeException: Erreur lors de la liaison du nom JNDI EJB.LoginRemote#EJB.LoginRemote pour l'EJB Login
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.initializeHome(BaseContainer.java:1553)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatefulSessionContainer.initializeHome(StatefulSessionContainer.java:213)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.ContainerFactoryImpl.createContainer(ContainerFactoryImpl.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.loadContainers(EjbApplication.java:230)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:108)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.load(ModuleInfo.java:186)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:264)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:460)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:212)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: javax.naming.NameAlreadyBoundException: Use rebind to override
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.doBindOrRebind(TransientContext.java:333)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.bind(TransientContext.java:268)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContextProviderImpl.bind(SerialContextProviderImpl.java:98)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.bind(LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.java:99)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.bind(SerialContext.java:672)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.bind(SerialContext.java:689)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.bind(InitialContext.java:423)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.bind(InitialContext.java:423)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.publishObject(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:208)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.publishObject(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:189)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer$JndiInfo.publish(BaseContainer.java:5629)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.initializeHome(BaseContainer.java:1540)
    ... 36 more
```

If anyone could tell me what I am doing wrong I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it not because you have the same EJB (with the same remote interface) in both projects? When you deploy the first one, it works fine. When you deploy the second one, Glassfish complains because there is a naming collision.